# One of Spring profiles is not actived despite adding it in environment variable

Tags: java, spring, profile

I have problem with activation of one of the Spring profiles. I've tried adding it as VM Option, environment variable, but with no success.
What is weird is the fact, that all other profiles are working properly.

I've tried to list active profiles using:

```
for (String profileName : environment.getActiveProfiles()) {
            System.out.println("Currently active profile - " + profileName)
}
```

And one I'm trying to enable is visible as "''".

[image]

Here are my VM Options  (Intellij) and listed profiles while app is running.
I have classes in my application that use @Profile("inappreports) annotation.
Anyone know what can be the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the problem was caused by WildFly config that was overriding env variable.